# How to generate a random string begining with lowercase letters and ending with lowercase letters?

Tags: bash

I try to write bash to generate string,combine lowercase letters+ 6 random characters +lowercase letters together.
But script is not workable as below:

```
    $(tr -dc 'a-z' </dev/urandom | head -c1)$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9$%*+-./ </dev/urandom | head -c 6); echo ''
    bash: f1XidWw: command not found
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see several potential problems; the biggest is that the way you're using `$( )`, it'll try to execute the result as a command. But what's the specific problem you're seeing? Any error messages?

Comment: @GordonDavisson,I am newbie to bash,output is `bash: f1XidWw: command not found`.

Comment: Of course you get this output: you generate the string `fiXidWw` and then ask bash to execute this string as a command!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a command

```
$(SOMETHING)
```

bash first executes `SOMETHING` as command, then collects its standard output, and replaces the original `$(....)` part with this standard output, which, since it is the only thing on the line, means that this standard output as a new command and executes that one too. For instance, the line

```
$(echo ls)
```

is just a ridiculously cumbersome way to execute a simple `ls`. In your case, you don't want the generated random string to be **executed**, but - for instance - being stored in a variable. Variable assignments in bash look like

```
VARNAME=STRING
```

Hence, if you do a

```
my_beautiful_random_string=$(tr -dc a-z </dev/urandom|head -c 1)$(tr -dc a-zA-Z </dev/urandom|head -c 6)$(tr -dc a-z </dev/urandom|head -c 1)
```

you would get your desired pattern on the variable `my_beautiful_random_string`. This would work, but the solution is a bit inefficient, because you create 6 child processes and 3 pipes fpr generating one string. If you worry about efficiency (for instance, because you are doing this in a loop), here are two alternatives:

You could (using your approach) create a single string of 7 mixed case characters and then convert the first and last one to lower case (see the paragraph on 'Case modification' in the bash man page). This would cost you only 2 child processes.

Alternatively, you could get rid of /dev/random and use the bash variable `RANDOM`. In this case you would first define a bash array holding the 26 characters of the alphabet, then for generating a single random character, calculate a random integer in this range  (using `$RANDOM`) and pick one element of this array. Repeat it 7 times and you have your string. If you do this properly, this does not need any child process at all, but the code is more complex.